# Need guide with laravel roles

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want start new project with `Laravel 5.4` in the past I used to work with different tables for different `user_types` but for this project I want to use default `users` table for all kind of users and just separate their access (roles), I'm not sure how to do that, that's why I need guide for it.

PS: to those friends that may want to ask for the codes, there is no codes yet! I need lead before start to coding so please don't comment spam.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Please atleast do a google search. Ref: https://github.com/httpoz/roles

Comment: @DavidMakogon as i said asking for `provide codes` is spam comment, because is guide question not a issue solver question so obviously there is no codes yet to people ask for it. `some people just put such a comment like that to get rank in this website!`

Answer (score 0):

assuming a user can have many roles, then to do this .. first is you have to have 3 tables .. `tbl_users`, `tbl_user_roles` and `tbl_roles` wherein

**tbl_users**

```
id
username
password
someotherfields
```

**tbl_user_roles**

```
id
user_id
role_id
```

**tbl_roles**

```
id
rolename
```

then in your `model user` you have to assign a relationship for the roles.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and now you have roles .. now how to have a page restriction depending on the role .. what you have to do is have a middleware for it .. here's how:

create a middleware called RolePermission, in your terminal run

```
php artisan make:middleware RolePermission
```

then in it's content

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    $roles = explode('|',$roles);
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles;
    foreach($userRoles as $role)
    {
        if(in_array($role->id, $roles))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    // Redirect
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

basically what it does is check if the authed user list roles is in the roles permitted to use a page ..

then adding a restriction to a page is in your routes file for example assuming that the role Administrator have id: 1, Moderator id: 2. SimpleUser id: 3 then the page User Management requires you to be administrator to enter, then have this:

```
// Group of route that will only be accessible for Users with Level = 1 (Administrator)
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'rolePermissions:1'], function(){
    Route::get('/users',['as'=>'users', 'uses'=>'PagesController@users']);
}

// Multiple roles for a page
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'rolePermissions:1|2|3|4'], function(){
    // routes here
}
```

in addition, that middleware doesn't yet work .. you must edit your kernel and add this under protected $routeMiddleware..

```
'rolePermissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\RolePermissions::class,
```

and it's all set, cheers .. you now have page restriction for authenticated user roles ..

Comment: @Deamonyowh hi, thanks for comment, now I make register users to be default in user roles and not admin or super admin etc?

Comment: it's up to you man .. you can either give a default role or the admin can give roles to users or both ..

Comment: i know it can be happen my question is `how`? and other issue that i have is i cannot get right part for right users by role name i tried this but no luck `@if (Auth::user()->role = 'isAdmin')
                    Welcome back Admin!
                  @else
                    Welcome back user!
                  @endif`